# Why is internet explorer randomly not clearly certain cookies?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cookies, jquery-cookie

For what it's worth, I'm using IE 10/11 (sometimes in 'edge' mode, sometimes in IE7 emulator mode), and instead of handling cookies directly I'm using JQuery Cookies.  Everything appears to work correctly in all other tested browsers.

---

I have a really weird problem.

My webapp needs to remember if a user has visited certain pages, and I'm using cookies to achieve this.  It works, but there is one odd error.  If I go in and reset all cookies (using the safety -> delete browsing history control), only *most* of them reset.  A few don't, and which ones don't is semi-random.  Certain ones never reset, others usually reset, others randomly choose not to reset.

I went in and interrogated my code, assuming it was a program error, but I tracked the code down directly to the cookies -- the cookie retrieval code is returning 'true' instead of 'undefined' for a lot of those cookies.

I set the cookies using the following code:

```
var id=$(this).attr('id');
$.cookie(id,true,{expires:3650});
```

The code to check the value of the cookie is:

```
var id=elem.attr('id');
var cookie=$.cookie(id);
```

I've stepped through in the debuggers, and id is being loaded with the correct values.  Cookie is (correctly) evalutated as 'undefined' in most instances, but in a few (one reliable, some random) is evaluating to true even after the cookies are reset.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How are you "resetting the cookies"?  How are you determining that they haven't been reset?  Show us that code.

Comment: @jfriend00 Code added, but it's so basic I doubt I could have screwed up the code.  I honestly would self-answer as IE bug, but how could they possibly have screwed something *this* basic up?

Comment: Where's the code that resets the cookies?

Comment: Also, do you realize that cookie values are strings, not booleans.

Comment: @jfriend00 There is no code that resets cookies; I'm doing this through the built-in tool to delete browsing history (which includes cookies).  As for the cookies being strings, you're quite correct, but in this case all I care about is whether the cookie exists or not.  I suspect JQueryCookies may be doing some magic to convert things to JSON for me, or maybe the browser is smart enough to know that 'true' should be transformed to boolean true.  Either way, it doesn't effect the operation of the above code in the least, so I went with the quickest, easiest to understand code possible.

Comment: Then these are the only possible explanations I can think of: 1) The browser has a bug and isn't clearing the cookie or 2) You are inadvertently creating the cookie before you test to see if it exists or 3) There is a logic problem when you test for the existence of the cookie.  Without a working/debuggable example, I'm not sure we can tell you which of these it might be.

Comment: Can you write steps to reproduce the bug like: *in ie10/11 open console and emulate ie7. Set a cookie `$.cookie('test', true,{expires:3650})`. Clear cache and refresh - check for cookie.*

Comment: @jfriend00 it looks like it may in fact have been a browser bug, because the same code just started working again...  and is now erroring out on a console.log line that it wasn't complaining about at all earlier.  Maybe the recent update left something in the browser in an inconsistent state?  Same code, different results.  (I'd be tempted to blame the reboot I did recently, but I did several reboots earlier while actively working on the code, so...)